# AWS CLI M1 chip installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, apple-m1

Do we need AWS CLI to be build for M1 chip architecture?
I feel like since its not compiling any code to be run on the system and rather it is just a way for the system to communicate with the AWS servers we wouldnt need it. Does my thinking make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`awscli`](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/) is a python tool. You can install it like any other python package, and it works perfectly fine on m1.

```
$ uname -sm
Darwin arm64
$ python --version --version  # twice gives more verbose version info
Python 3.9.13 (main, May 24 2022, 21:13:51)
[Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)]
$ pip install awscli
...lots of stuff...
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.25.2 Python/3.9.13 Darwin/21.5.0 botocore/1.27.2
```

Comment: It should be noted this is only true for v1 of the AWS CLI.  v2 is available, and includes some new features that will never be backported to v1.